# How to compute confidence intervals for a scaled reciprocal normal statistic

Tags: confidence-interval, data-transformation, bootstrap, back-transformation

I have the following statistic of which I want to compute confidence intervals:
\begin{equation}
Z = \frac{(X-Y)^{-1}}{\mathbb{PVE}[(X-Y)^{-1}]},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
X &\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\sigma_{1}^{2},\frac{2\sigma_{1}^{4}}{n-1}\right),\\
Y &\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\sigma_{2}^{2},\frac{2\sigma_{2}^{4}}{m-1}\right),
\end{align}
$n$ and $m$ are the sample sizes used to compute $X$ and $Y$ and $\mathbb{PVE}[(X-Y)^{-1}]$ is the Cauchy principal value for the expected value of $(X-Y)^{-1}$ (it's just a constant) defined as
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{PVE}[(X-Y)^{-1}] = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma_{X-Y}}\,\mathcal{D}_{+}\left(\frac{\mu_{X-Y}}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_{X-Y}}\right),
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{D}_{+}(z)$ is the [dawson function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html). I have parametric equations for the pdf/cdf of $Z$. Computing exact confidence intervals seems completely out of the question.

> **For my application, very large sample sizes are the norm (i.e. $n$ and $m$ on the order of several thousands). It is also typical for $\mathrm{Pr}[(X-Y)\leq0]\approx 0$. How can I go about computing confidence intervals of $Z$? What options do I have in this specific application?**